# Build extjs with gulp

Tags: javascript, extjs, build, gulp

senchacmd is just a great tool but build time is a bit high. Does some one have a good way how to speed up the building process?

kind regards

Answer (score 4):

it was a long weekend because of a German official holiday and I fiddled a bit in the gulp universe. I decided to write a tiny plugin to give extjs an entry point. It tells gulp what dependency order it has to be.

It feels odd when I'm thinking about file reading, concatenating, and minimizing but I just quote my shell:

> [19:54:25] Finished 'my40kLinesApp' after 6.5 ms

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-extify

software and hardware progressions is just amazing. Thanks god JavaScript is great.

enjoy your sunday